# Google Play Console says internal test is available, but it's not

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have created an internal release of an Android app on the Google Play console. When I copy the opt-in link and paste it into the browser, and then click the link to install the app, I get this Not Found page.
[image: Not Found]

According to the Play Console, the Internal Testing Track is not active, but it's been 5+ days.

Here's what's *not* the problem:

- All the app details are filled in, and the Play Console says the app is available to internal testers
- I am logged into a Google account that is on the internal testers list
- The release is over five days old, so it should be done processing
- The opt-in link is available

Comment: I have the same issue. I will keep you posted if I am able to solve the issue

Comment: @brmk My internal release finally started working, see answer below.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a customer support question, and not about programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is that 48 hours may be considered typical, but my internal test was not ready until a full week after its upload to the Play Console. During that week, I put in a ticket with Google developer support, but never got a response. My recommendation is to wait for a week, and then put in a support ticket if it's still not up by then, and hope they respond.

Answer (score 6):

Same issue - our app wasn't available after 48 hours, so I reached out. I quickly got this reply, which is unfortunate:

*Hi,
Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support!

Please note that your app submission to the internal test track is still processing which is the reason it's not accessible via it's opt-in link yet.

Due to adjusted work schedules at this time, we are currently experiencing longer than usual review times. While the situation is currently evolving, app review times may fluctuate, and may take 7 days or longer.
Moving forward, we recommend you adjust your planning to account for this and avoid resubmitting, as each update or change to your app will cause the review process to start over from the very beginning. We understand the inconvenience this may cause and thank you for your patience and understanding.
If you have any other questions about using the Play Console, please let me know and I’ll be happy to help.

Regards,
Suraj
Google Play Developer Support*

Comment: What's the best way to contact Google about this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

Wow! I am on day 4 now and my app is still "being reviewed"... The Internal Testing Url is still not working... My app got rejected because of some wording in my description that violated their content policy. The reason for rejection was very vague and didn't say what it was. I cleaned up anything/everything including the term "youtube videos" and saved it. So when they emailed me the "rejection" email (Day 2) I went and checked the Google Play Console and it still said being reviewed and didn't mention anything about the rejection...
Google needs to overhaul that entire system because it is virtually un-usable! They may as have have used white text over a white background! Geesh!

My iphone app review process with Apple was done in 2 days! Much better experience!

Comment: So the internal testing link works now. It took 6 days for it to be reviewed by google play (The review process was started on 3 Nov 2020 and today for the first time, the internal tester url link works).....

Comment: Thank you for confirming. Hope this issue can serve as a heads up to anyone in the future with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

App releases on the Internal testing track may or may not be subjected to a review. If it is the first release on the track, it is very likely to be reviewed. Reviews can take days or minutes, and from experience, it is best to plan for about 7 days (safest side) in the app review process in Play Store.

Google PlayStore does not provide expedited review like Apple AppStore does. PlayStore's Internal testing track also has nitty-gritty details in its working, which I never found any documentation for, and had to learn them the hard way.

Maybe this post helps: https://medium.com/@tukai.anirban/internal-testing-in-google-playstore-47de955062ad
(Disclaimer: I wrote this post after facing various hurdles when getting my latest app through Play Store)