# Google Play Console - Internal Testing link does not work

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have an app published to Google Play Console for Internal Testing i.e. I just want this app to be available to certain users.  Below is the current summary of the app;

[image]

Note this is the second release i 'tried' to see if there will be any difference; I first uploaded a .AAB file then in the latest release I uploaded the .APK file.

[image]

Below is the link I send to my testers;

[image]

Issue is that when a tester clicks on the link, they opt in the 'programme' and have an option to download it on google play.  When they click on that link, its either just infinite loading or a message to say `the requested URL was not found on this server.`

- Please note this app has not been published to the play store as a
  live version.
- This is the first time the app has been uploaded to internal testing.
- The app has been first published for internal testing last Friday (6th of Nov) and now is 9th of Nov.

On the dashboard, there is an announcement as shown below but I cannot see anywhere the 'status' of the app i.e. to say its being reviewed etc.

[image]

**Reply from Google;**

I understand you have some concerns about app pending issue. Please note that after you submit a new app or an update to an existing app on your Play Console, it can take some time for your app to be processed for publishing on Google Play. Any time you make a change to your app while a review is already pending will mean the review period starts over. Furthermore, any submissions can't be retrieved or cancelled. As a result, we recommend you adjust your planning to account for this and avoid resubmitting.

For certain developer accounts, we’ll take more time to thoroughly review your app(s) to help better protect users. This may result in review times of up to 7 days or longer in exceptional cases. You can always view the current status on your Publishing overview page. When the review is completed, you will see "You don't have any changes in review" under Changes in review section. In addition, we would also like to remind you that if you turned on the managed publishing mode, your update won't be published until you click "Review and publish."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Play Console says internal test is available, but it's not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296562/google-play-console-says-internal-test-is-available-but-its-not)

Comment: Readers note that OP @Aleksandar Zoric added a comment on accepted answer, "Just had to wait - worked in the end. Think it was about 4 days before testers could install the app."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Facing the same issue. Uploaded a new app on Nov 6th. Still waiting for the app to be available on the play store for internal tests. Followed the procedure to enable internal app sharing from the play store app which is:

1. Go to settings on the play store app
2. Tap on play store version seven times to enable internal app sharing
3. Enable internal app sharing.

Even after following this procedure, the app is still inaccessible to my internal testers. From research, I've concluded it might be due to the IARC content rating not having been accepted yet https://stackoverflow.com/a/63651644.

UPDATE: I was able to get my app available to testers later on by going to Publish Overview and clicking on 'Review and publish' button.

Comment: I came across that post too and hoping that this is the case; a waiting game.  And yes, all of our testers followed the same procedure as you mentioned above.

Comment: Just had to wait - worked in the end.  Think it was about 4 days before testers could install the app.

Comment: @AleksandarZoric Did you do click the 'Review and Publish' button anyways? Or just left it to Google, we don't have any IARC email so confused what takes so long

Comment: @yahms23 I created a release in Internal Testing > uploaded APK > added description > clicked on review release > clicked on roll out release.  We don't have an IARC email either and yet took 4 days.  I did get a reply from Google (I sent them an email about this.  See above for reply)

Comment: I have the same issue and my IARC says completed. I am publishing the app in internal testing phase but get NOT FOUND ON SERVER and event play store gives nothing.

Comment: @Mahdi-Jafaree some things I noted, check under Publishing Overview if there's any action needed from your end, this only applies if managed publishing is set to on. Also for internal test use the opt-in link found in internal testing under testers tab. If all that is fine then it's just a matter of waiting till the app is available.

Comment: @Faddablack testing has nothing in Publishing and Overview and the link under testers tab is available. but it says not found on this server. however, I have published it and its in review don't know how much time it will take. not to be confused, there are two releases: one is test which is not found on server. another is production which is in-review

Comment: @Mahdi-Jafaree from my experience it took a while (around 4 days) until the app was available to testers. If your IARC says it is completed, the app will show up eventually give it 3-4 days.

Comment: @Faddablack hope so!

Comment: @Faddablack how long does it took for you to publish the app. I have submitted my app on 11 of Jan 2021 and it been 4 working days but no update has been received. I tried ever possible thing.

Comment: @ZahidAli for me it took 4 days before the app was available. I would suggest you check on your play console dashboard iff any action is required from your end. Also confirm on Publish overview if  Managed publishing is set to on (meaning you have to manually make the app available after it has been approved) or off (app will be automatically made available after being approved

Comment: @Faddablack the Publish overview is set off which mean the app will will be automatically made available after being approved. Still it has been 5 days and the app is in review stage. Although I tried to publish on open testing and closed testing tracks. I suspect that updating the tracks recently might have started the review time from beginning.

Comment: @ZahidAli I see, in that case then it's just a matter of waiting, any action required from you will appear on the dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Now my app is visible to internal testers.
[image]
You have to finish all the checks and formalities before your app shows up on the Play Store like agreeing to the tncs and privacy policy, adding descriptions, screenshots, etc. I also enabled sharing of app via URL by going to Setup > Internal app sharing